# Should CAN bus in a vehicle be isolated?

Tags: can

I'm wondering whether to use an isolated CAN transceiver or not. A few of the nodes in the vehicle use a TI ISO1050 which has an isolated power supply and run GND and 5 V with CAN-Low and CAN-High signals so they have a common ground. I wanted to use a TI SN65HVD232 because of the reduced package size and no need for an isolated power supply.

I'm unsure if I should use an isolated transceiver like the ISO1050 or not.  Will I run into problems if I don't use an isolated transceiver?

This system is non-critical. It's just for data logging.

Comment: At what data rate? 500 kbit/s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not whether *your* system is critical, but whether there are *any* critical functions that will fail if the bus is disabled (made unavailable for any communication) by a fault on your "non-critical" device.

A bus means that all devices share a common channel of communication. If your device holds the bus in a non-idle condition, it will prevent all other devices from using it (or more precisely, that segment of it).

In general, vehicle systems are isolated to both: (1) isolate failing bus devices from impacting the remaining bus-attached devices and (2) prevent high-voltage transients and other power/signal issues that occur in vehicles from damaging bus-attached devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just for datalogging, then I presume this data logging device is a computer or handheld device that has its own power supply. In such case the galvanic isolation between these two separate systems seems the right way to go. without galvanic isolation you can face a risk of destroying all devices on CAN bus, that would mean your car is on the way to the junkyard, as well the PC connected.

Answer (score 0):

At some cases a galvanic isolation is required by international standards. For example a high voltage battery for electric or hybrid vehichles. They usually do not have a connection to the 12V ground and therefore the CAN bus of the battery controller may need galvanic isolation to the 12V Boardnet.